# If statement in R with multiple arguments

Tags: r, if-statement

After reading the comments section and then making the following changes, I am still getting a 'Success' instead of a 'Failure':

```
nrow(statedata)
[1] 100
num = -1
if(num != "best" & num != "worst" & num < 1 & num > nrow(statedata))
    print("Failure!?")
else <br />
    print("Success!")
[1] "Success!"
```

Comment: Thanks, actually it should be num > nrow(statedata). I read you comment after I tested and corrected this. This is part of a larger function, which I am trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Note that `|` and `&` are vectorized. For a single comparison you might want to consider `||` and `&&`.

Comment: @Jeroen When applied to vectors of length >1, `&&` and `||` silently use the first element.  `if` issues a warning in this case, so perhaps using `&` and `|` is to be preferred.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
if(num != "best" & num != "worst" & (num < 1 | num > nrow(statedata)))
```

Thanks to all!
Cheers.

Logical errors are so hard to find.

Comment: It is better to accept the answer posted by @ak0053792, not repost it as your own.

Comment: But it didn't solve the problem, my answer did and it is different.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the condition:

```
if(num != "best" | num != "worst" | num < 1 | num > length(10))
```

You should use AND not OR in negation, else the other statement will always be true. I hope you got my point here.

Comment: No question is dumb, mate. I stuck such scenario previously. And i guess you learn from experience. Happy learning.